# Has it been considered to leverage the Stack Exchange network more directly as a learning platform?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There is so much great information on Stack Exchange. A lot of it one discovers only on a need to know basis when running into a similar situation. I was thinking about a new feature to leverage this.

I think that Stack Exchange holds great value in turning its old questions (which already have answers) into a more direct learning experience. Let us say I'm a user that wants to learn more about a specific topic. SE has some knowledge of my skill level on that topic. If not it can try to estimate it by presenting me with questions which already have answers. If I feel comfortable with answering the questions I receive, and the answers are familiar terrain, I can give feedback on how confident I am in resolving the question and also how entertaining the question is as a learning experience. This way SE can update my skill level and update the difficulty and meta information of the question. With this closed feedback loop it can then continue providing me with questions which are relevant to my skill level. Once I'm at a high skill level it could then occasionally present me with questions which don't have an answer as well.

Do you think this makes sense? Would you use it or do you think it would help attract new users to the site and teach them how to write higher quality answers?

Comment: Well, what is this trying to achieve that voting and filtering by tags haven't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't expect users to step in on a particular level. SE is not a school, which educates its users so they reach a higher level (there have been some initiatives, but they died silently, like SO.TV).

If you present 'low-level' questions to new users to answer, what benefit would that have? Isn't it we are trying to minimize the number of low-level questions? We definitely don't want to encourage bad behavior.

Also it seems to me it is very hard to determine which questions are difficult or not. I can be an expect in one of the tags on a question and a noob on another one... That doesn't qualify in any way how contributing my answer can be.

I think this is a nice idea, but not for SE.

Comment: "I think this is a nice idea, but not for SE." - Well the content itself is cc by-sa 3.0 (with attribution required), so I guess someone else could use this content and build such a system. But yeah, I don't think it's in SE interest to do so.

Comment: Indeed, good point. Feel free to build this your own!

Comment: Ok, cool, I'll consider it :)